# Adding quote to TextField using WatiN

Tags: .net, watin

I have a web page being tested by WatiN. One of the tests writes three characters into a text field using

```
textfield.SetAttributeValue("value", "\"BI");
```

That works fine. The three characters trigger some search suggestions to appear below the textfield (implemented as <a> links within a list <ul><li>).

The test chooses to ignore the search suggestions and carry on typing, e.g.

```
textfield.AppendText("G BEN\"");
```

Making the entire text inputted "BIG BEN" (including the quotes).

The problem is that when the the final " is appended, odd things happen. First the previous character in the field, N is deleted. Then focus moves to one of the search suggestions and clicks on it (all code that could possibly do this is definitely disabled) and then finally the final quote is added to the field. If I change the final character to a # then everything behaves. & also misbehaves in the same way as quote.

I'm using IE8 and the latest WatiN. I need to input the quotes as it changes the search behaviour.

Any ideas what could be happening and suggestions for a work-around?